# Callback function with Nodejs + Mongoose, How to return only the search value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I already researched how to do this, but I still can not understand, where am I going wrong ? 
I researched how to do this type of function but I could not understand how to get an answer in my callback, always end up having 2 functions within the other.

> Controller UserCtrl

```
    // Models
    var User = require('../models/user');

    var isUserSearch = function(email,callback){

        User.find({email:email},function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            return callback(data);
        });

    }

    var isUser = function(email){

        var resp = isUserSearch(email,function(data){
            return data;
            console.log(data); // I get my data 
        });

        console.log("Response : " + resp); // undefined

        return resp;

    }

    var result = {
        gerarToken : gerarToken,
        isUser : isUser,
    }

    module.exports = result;
```

> Model

```
// Model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        require : true,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    type : {
        type : Number,
        required : true,
        default : 1
    },
    created : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now
    }
});

var Data = mongoose.model('User', Schema);

module.exports = Data;
```

> Context AuthCtrl

```
// Controllers

var Crypto = require('./cryptoCtrl');

var User = require('./UserCtrl');

// ----------- Login
var login = function(req,res){
    var data = req.body;
    var email = data.email;
    var password = Crypto.cryptoString(data.password);

    var existUser = User.isUser(email);

    if(existUser){

        // IsUser is a function to return the user array 
        // if it exists, otherwise it returns only a false 
        // boolean value. In the example I'm going to use this function

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resp = isUserSearch(email,function(data){
  return data;
  console.log(data); // I get my data 
});

console.log("Response : " + resp); // undefined
```

`resp` is undefined due to *non-blocking asynchronous architecture* node.js provide.

The line which you are trying to logging the value is executed when the function that return the data `isUserSearch` has not already finished.

Did you already try to call `isUserSearch` rather than `isUser` in you controller?

```
var login = function(req,res){
    var data = req.body;
    var email = data.email;
    var password = Crypto.cryptoString(data.password);

    User.isUser(email, function(existUser) {
       if(existUser){
          console.log('User exist', existUser);
        // IsUser is a function to return the user array 
        // if it exists, otherwise it returns only a false 
        // boolean value. In the example I'm going to use this function
       } else {
          console.log('User does not exist');
       }
    });
}
```

Then you can remove `isUser` and change:

```
var result = {
    gerarToken : gerarToken,
    isUser: isUserSearch,
}
```

Comment: I'm beginning to understand, you know the right way for me to do this. What do I need to study specifically for this, can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `isUserSearch` function with the callback. Use the data returned in a callback in the `AuthCtrl` and you call this as:

**Controller UserCtrl**:

```
// Models
var User = require('../models/user');

var isUserSearch = function(email, callback){
    /* use findOne() which returns a single document that you can check if null */
    User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, user){ 
        if (err) throw err;
        return callback(!!user); // return a callback with a Boolean value as argument
    });
}

var result = {
    gerarToken : gerarToken,
    isUser: isUserSearch,
}

module.exports = result;
```

**Context AuthCtrl**:

```
// Controllers

var Crypto = require('./cryptoCtrl');

var User = require('./UserCtrl');

// ----------- Login
var login = function(req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    var email = data.email;
    var password = Crypto.cryptoString(data.password);

    /* Call the isUser function with a callback */
    User.isUser(email, function(userExists){
        if (userExists) {
            // userExists is a boolean value
        }
    });

}
```